# SQL 2005 cannot delete user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, user-management

I have restored a database from a backup onto a new server, and I cannot delete the old schema from the database.  I have created a NEW user for this database.  The NEW user is named differently (to make things clearer for other developers), so I have no use for this schema.  I DID manage to delete the USER finally, but the schema won't go away.

The error I receive is "Cannot drop schema '' because it is being referenced by object ''

Running this script:

```
select * from sys.objects where schema_id = 5
```

...shows all the objects this schema 'owns'.

My problem is I cannot find a way to change the ownership of these objects.  There must be a way?
Thanks all

Comment: Was the backup from a SQL Server 2000 server installation - or from another 2005 installation?

Comment: Yes, I am moving from SQL 2000 to SQL 2005, so the backup is of the SQL 2000 variety, moving into SQL 2005 environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax to move object Thing from schema Source to schema Destination is:

```
ALTER SCHEMA Destination TRANSFER Source.Thing
```

[Here's SQL](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=31693215&threadid=31693208) to generate a script to transfer all objects to the dbo schema:

```
SELECT 'ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER ' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '.' + name
FROM sys.tables
WHERE schema_id != SCHEMA_ID('dbo');
```

To just transfer one particular schema:

```
SELECT 'ALTER SCHEMA NewSchema TRANSFER ' + SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '.' + name
FROM sys.tables
WHERE schema_name(schema_id) = 'OldSchema'
```

Comment: ALTER SCHEMA Destination TRANSFER Source.Thing
exactly what i was looking for - thanks!